# show sequence $n^2+1$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

> Question: Show $S_n = n^2+1$ diverges.

My understanding of this question is proof by contradiction.
We first assume that $n^2+1$ converges to $s$. This implies that fix $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ s.t. $|n^2+1-s|< \epsilon$. I'm stuck here. anyhelp?

Comment: what is $S_n$? a partial sum?

Comment: Oh it is a sequence

Comment: I presume from the sounds of things that OP has been asked to show that $n^2 + 1$ is divergent via definitions. Else it's trivial.

Comment: @SeanZhou As you said, supposing that $n^2+1$ converges to $s$ implies that for every $\epsilon>0$ THERE IS an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n\geq N$, $|n^2+1-s|<\epsilon$. If some $\epsilon>0$ fails this condition, then the sequence defined by $S_n=n^2+1$ is not convergent. Pick $\epsilon=1>0$, and notice that the inequality above implies that for some $N$ and whenever $n\geq N$,  $n^2+1<s+\epsilon \Rightarrow n^2+1<s+1 \Rightarrow n^2<s$. Notice that $n$ can be taken as large as you want... do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Yes thanks. I see the contradiction here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A convergent sequence is bounded.  Your sequence is unbounded.

Comment: I think this is a good point but this is my first analysis class and we haven't defined the boundness of a sequence, so I guess I cannot use this argument.

Comment: Fair enough.  Well, then you can argue as follows: suppose the sequence convergence to some number $L$.  This will lead to a contradiction.  Namely, since the terms of the sequence get further and further apart:
$$
(n+1)^2 - n^2 > 2n,
$$
it follows that no subsequence of $S_{n}$ can be contained in any neighhborhood of any number $L$.

Comment: Actually, much simpler than all this gymnastics, would be to prove, as a first part of your solution, that a convergent sequence must be bounded, or, to avoid the word "bounded", must be contained in some interval $[a, b]$ (a two-liner proof, once you know the statement).  And then use the argument I suggested.:)

Answer (score 1):

use that $$S_n=n^2+1\geq 2n$$ and the sequence $2n$ is divergent

Comment: It is a good idea.. And in this case we still need to show why 2n is divergent right? I'm taking my first mathematical analysis class so can you specify how to rigorously do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that for any natural number $N$ there is some $k$ such that $S_{n} > N$ for all $n > k$.

Answer (score 1):

$\forall\ N \in \mathbb{N}_{\ >\ 0}\,\,,\quad
n > \left\lfloor\,\sqrt{\,{N - 1}\,}\,\right\rfloor \implies n^{2} + 1 > N$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B > 1$ be given. We will show that for any such $B$ we can choose an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $S_N \geq B$. This will show that the sequence diverges to $\infty$. Given $B$ we can choose $N > \sqrt{B - 1}$. Since $B > 1$, $N$ is well defined. Now solving for $N$ gives us $S_N = N^2 + 1 > B$. Thus we can choose an $N$ that will make our sequence larger than any number larger than $1$. This tells us the sequence diverges to $\infty$